# Zod validation for phone numbers

Tags: zod

I am new to using zod for valiadtion. I have read through the documentation but I can see anything on how to add a validation for a phone number.

I used the email one to make sure a user enters a correct email, but how do I do the same for a phone number.

Currently it looks like this:

```
contactNumber: z
    .string()
    .min(10, { message: 'Must be a valid mobile number' })
    .max(14, { message: 'Must be a valid mobile number' }),
```

I am just not sure this is correct. I have made it a string because I want the user to be able to put a + in front of the number if necessary for example: +27823456787. I don't want the user to be able to put any letters in the number example: 072r536e98, If the user puts letters I want an error message to say "Must be a valid number".

Can anyone maybe advise me on the correct why to do the validation?

Comment: You cannot be advised if you don't specify what format you are requiring for a phone number.

Comment: Phone numbers are incredibly more complex than emails. For one, emails are global, while phone numbers formats vary for each region. So first come up with your "correct" format, then we can think about validation.

Answer (score 16):

you can use regex, it worked for me =D.

```js
const phoneRegex = new RegExp(
  /^([+]?[\s0-9]+)?(\d{3}|[(]?[0-9]+[)])?([-]?[\s]?[0-9])+$/
);

const schema = z.object({
     phone: z.string().regex(phoneRegex, 'Invalid Number!'),
})
```

Answer (score 15):

You could use a `zod` [`refinement`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#refine) to chain together a check from a library that is more capable of making that check. As was mentioned in the comments, the rules are complicated, and specific to the region.

There seems to be a validation from [validator.js](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) for example that could handle refining the `string` to a mobile phone number with `isMobilePhone` but you may want/need to have the user specify the country they are in.

An example of how this would work might be:

```js
import { z } from "zod";
import validator from "validator";

const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  phone: z.string().refine(validator.isMobilePhone)
});

console.log(
  schema.safeParse({
    name: "test",
    phone: "+1-212-456-7890"
  })
); // Success

console.log(
  schema.safeParse({
    name: "test",
    phone: "2124567890"
  })
); // Success

console.log(
  schema.safeParse({
    name: "test",
    phone: "1234"
  })
); // Failure
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [`libphonenumber-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js) to enforce strict validation, and to convert all phone numbers to a consistent format.

```js
import parsePhoneNumberFromString from 'libphonenumber-js';
import { z } from 'zod';

export const zPhone = z.string().transform((arg, ctx) => {
  const phone = parsePhoneNumberFromString(arg, {
    // set this to use a default country when the phone number omits country code
    defaultCountry: 'NG',
    
    // set to false to require that the whole string is exactly a phone number,
    // otherwise, it will search for a phone number anywhere within the string
    extract: false,
  });

  // when it's good
  if (phone && phone.isValid()) {
    return phone.number;
  }

  // when it's not
  ctx.addIssue({
    code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
    message: 'Invalid phone number',
  });
  return z.NEVER;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this format

```
const schema user = z.object({
    mobile_number: z.string().refine((value) => /^[+]{1}(?:[0-9-()/.]\s?){6,15}[0-9]{1}$/.test(value)),
})
```